# Make portfolio thumbnail clickable rather than just icon

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make my portfolio thumbnails clickable, rather than just an icon within the hover.

I have managed to hide the icon with:

```
.mk-jupiter-icon-arrow-circle::before {
content:" ";
}
```

However am unsure how to make the link itself cover the whole thumbnail. Any help would be appreciated!

page link: http://ej.electricmustard-dev.co.uk/work/

Example of the current link area: http://i57.tinypic.com/29yjkhj.png

Comment: Wrap the `feature-image` div in an anchor...or wrap the `img` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the overlay covers the entire image on hover all you would have to do is wrap a anchor around it.

```
<a href="..."> <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div> </a>
```

Comment: Appologies for asking what I imagine is a silly que. How would I add this and would it be per thumbnail or just once?

Comment: A wordpress page is divided into 3 main sections (ish) header, content and footer. Your thumbnails will be in the content part of the page so you will have to find a file called "content.php" etc and find the **theme-page** div. Inside that is where you add the <a> to **image-hover-overlay**.